# How to use Haskell "json" package to parse to type [Map String String]?

Tags: json, haskell

I've got some sample JSON data like this:

```
[{
  "File:FileSize": "104 MB",
  "File:FileModifyDate": "2015:04:11 10:39:00-07:00",
  "File:FileAccessDate": "2016:01:17 22:37:23-08:00",
  "File:FileInodeChangeDate": "2015:04:26 07:50:50-07:00"
}]
```

and I'm trying to parse the data using the [json](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json) package (not [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)):

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M
import Text.JSON

content <- readFile "file.txt"
decode content :: Result [M.Map String String]
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error "readJSON{Map}: unable to parse array value"
```

I can get as far as this:

```
fmap 
  (map (M.fromList . fromJSObject)) 
  (decode content :: Result [JSObject String])
```

but it seems like an awfully manual way to do it. Surely the JSON data could be parsed directly into a type `[Map String String]`. Pointers?

Comment: have you tried the `MAP_AS_DICT` switch? (see the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-0.9.1/docs/src/Text-JSON.html#JSON)) - I guess the first version does not know how to handle the object into a map

Comment: @Carsten I guess I would need to recompile if I wanted to use that switch. Something I'd like to avoid if possible ...

Comment: well yes - this, keep your version or switch to aeson - atm I don't see another way (but I never used this package before and only had a quick glance at haddock)

Comment: don't thank me (I could not help) - maybe someone will see this and give you a real answer yet

Comment: @Carsten Well, `decode content :: Maybe [Map String String]` works with Aeson so I'm pretty happy although not quite what I was going with.

Answer (score 1):

Without `MAP_AS_DICT` switch, the `JSON (MAP a b)` instance will be:

```
instance (Ord a, JSON a, JSON b) => JSON (M.Map a b) where
  showJSON = encJSArray M.toList
  readJSON = decJSArray "Map" M.fromList
```

So only JSON array can be parsed to Data.Map, otherwise it will call `mkError` and terminate.

Due to haskell's restriction on instances, you won't be able to write an instance for `JSON (Map a b)` yourself, so your current workaround may be the best solution.